# Customizing the functionality of the Monoprice graphic tablet's buttons?

Tags: macos, scrolling, plist, graphics-tablet

I'd like to re-map the pen buttons of my Monoprice graphics tablet ([this one](http://www.monoprice.com/Product/?c_id=108&cp_id=10841&cs_id=1084101&p_id=10593&seq=1&format=2#description)) to do other things than those that are enabled through the official application? Currently, I can only assign the pen buttons to execute variations of regular mouse clicks (single and double left/right clicks). But I'd like to be able to use them for other purposes, for example to register middle button clicks (which is not an option to choose from on Mac). So is there any way I can accomplish this? **Perhaps through hacking the plist file?**

I'm on a Macbook Pro running on OSX Mavericks

Comment: While a bit different from your original, cross-posting is not encouraged, so you might want to delete one of your questions.

Comment: Fair enough. Is it ok if I wait to see if this one picks up speed first, though? Just a day or so.

Comment: Sure, that's fine with me.